# Is there a word for everything you do at the master and PhD level?

Tags: word-request

I am thinking of *"post-bachelor"*, but I am wondering if there's a better word for it. Here's an example:

> These post-bachelor courses are only required if you want to complete
>   a master degree.

Could there be a non-composite noun or adjective?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the US, this would be **graduate** coursework. Graduate school (sometimes shortened to grad school) refers to programs that grant master's degrees and doctorates.

Comment: Note that in the UK, the more common term is "**postgraduate**"; graduate tends not to be used in this way.

Comment: @SteveMelnikoff Thanks for the info, Steve, edited to reflect that this is a US perspective!

Comment: Canada is the same as the US.  You could say graduate research for research with a prof while a student.  Post graduate research / work would be after your Ph.D. (say as in a post-doctoral fellowship position) before you become assistant professor

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the term is ["graduate school"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graduate_schoolprograms):

> A graduate school (sometimes shortened as grad school) is a school that awards advanced academic degrees (i.e. master's and doctoral degrees) with the general requirement that students must have earned a previous undergraduate (bachelor's) degree.

There is often a distinction between *graduate* school programs, which award Master's and Doctoral degrees, and *professional* school programs, which award degrees in things like medicine, law, business, engineering, education, etc.

Comment: The second paragraph is again not true of the UK: all of these Masters and doctoral degrees would be postgraduate.